# Centre Google map within bootstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I am using two Google maps with set sizes inside a single Bootstrap row split into two "col-md-6".  The problem is that I can't get the maps to centre within the columns.

I've tried placing the maps within another div, and applying a class such as:

```
.centre {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I have used this approach on the containing div and the map canvas itself.

I have also tried the Bootstraps center-block class.

Why won't this work?  Is it because the map is generated by the script? However I also used some other script widget which I could centre no problem.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="center-block">
        <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script>
        <div style='overflow:hidden;height:400px;width:400px;'>
            <div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:400px;width:400px;'></div>
            <style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style>
        </div>
        <a href='https://embed-map.org/'>adding google maps to website</a>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=de6f66c1083e8292c0be178f836c7b9580eaf39f'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function init_map() {
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5963138,-2.2334897000000637),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5963138,-2.2334897000000637)
                });
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '<strong>The Cherwell Wellbeing Hub</strong><br>Cherwell Avenue<br>OL10 4SY Heywood<br>'
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="center-block">
        <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script>
        <div style='overflow:hidden;height:400px;width:400px;'>
            <div id='gmap_canvas1' style='height:400px;width:400px;'></div>
            <style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style>
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=79bf837985bd36410db02fbfc1b92f01d77d4475'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function init_map() {
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.41196129999999,-2.7916708999999855),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas1'), myOptions);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.41196129999999,-2.7916708999999855)
                });
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '<strong>Grenfell House</strong><br>Widness Road<br>WA8 6AX Widnes<br>'
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show complete HTML code including the google script.

Comment: Can you please provide your complete code to check your error???

Comment: Maybe putting to maps "width:100%"

Comment: @RachelS edited with html

Comment: @AnkitGupta added the code

Answer (score 1):

Works fine by me: http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/LZZJaP

All you need is `text-align:center` on the divs housing the google maps.